# Hibernate Error: NULL at org.hibernate.param.PositionalParameterSpecification.bind(PositionalParameterSpecification.java:55)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

What does the following Hibernate error mean? We have existing code that used to work before a Spring/Hibernate upgrade.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.param.PositionalParameterSpecification.bind(PositionalParameterSpecification.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:682) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindPreparedStatement(Loader.java:2150) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2127) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2059) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2037) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
```

On this DAO method:

```
@Query("select s from TraineeSearch s where s.trainDirectorNedId=?1 and s.nedId in?2 and s.plan IS NOT NULL and s.currentPlan ='Y'")
List<TraineeSearch> getTerminatedTrainees(String nedId,List<String> nedIds);
```

Answer (score 1):

Support for ? i.e query parameter has been removed in Hibernate 5.3.

You need to use named parameters in the query.

```
@Query("select s from TraineeSearch s where s.trainDirectorNedId=:nedIdParameter and s.nedId in:nedIdsParameter and s.plan IS NOT NULL and s.currentPlan ='Y'")
List<TraineeSearch> getTerminatedTrainees(String nedId,List<String> nedIds);
```

and then set following parameters

```
query.setParameter("nedIdParameter ", nedId);
query.setParameter("nedIdsParameter ", nedIds);
```

You can refer this migration guide.

http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Hibernate_5.3_Migration_Guide#Positional_Parameters_are_not_Supported

Comment: Maybe `PositionalParameterSpecification` shows that this hibernate version used implements the positional parameters, I would rather think that the problem is here : `in?2`. I would say you need at least a space in between and maybe brackets around the `?2`.